# Importing declaration file from node_modules folder in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, immutable.js

I downloaded the package "immutable" from the package manager "npm" and its file "package.json" has a property "typings" with the value `node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.d.ts`

The problem is when I try to use it from a class I get the error `TS2307 (TS) Cannot find module 'immutable'`

```
import { Immutable } from "immutable"; // error here

export class RestRepository<T = IEntityBase> extends BasicRepository<T>
{
    private c: Immutable.Foo;
}
```

I understand that theproperty `exclude` from tsconfig excludes all file inside `node_modules`folder (except `node_modules/@typings`) but "@typings/immutable" does not have ts files but a `readme.md`

**README.md**

> This is a stub types definition for Facebook's Immutable (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js).
>
> Facebook's Immutable provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/immutable installed!

Any help would be very appreciated!

-
tsc 2.6

Comment: You don't need installing the definitions because they are already included in the module - look inside immutable/dist and you will find it  - and this is clear in the read.md. I tried to compile with a tsconfig with "exclude": ["node_modules"] option and it worked - using tsc 2.6.1. I used VScode 1.18.0 and when I typed some function exposed by the library, the editor imported it automatically.

Comment: As a sanity check, just try to import some function you are positive that exists in the library like _import_ {Stack} _from_ _"immutable"_;

Comment: Hi!, my target is ES6,.. I don't know if my target is the problem... I will try to create a new project and change my target to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue here - how did you solve this??

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Immutable. The only way I could fix it was to do the following 3 steps:

1) Copy the immutable.d.ts file to the root of the app which in my case was the same level as my index.ts

2) Import the immutable **namespace** as you have above (step one prevented this from showing an error)

3) Import the functions I actually wanted to use i.e. Map etc

This left me with the following:

```
import * as Immutable from "immutable";
import { Map } from "immutable";
```

Only then could I both get rid of the error on the namespace import (which for me was preventing a release build) and import the actual feature I was attempting to use (Map).